# Creating Private Methods in AngularJS Controllers

Tags: angularjs

What is the way to create private methods in an AngularJS controllers?

I have currently done it like this, but I wonder whether it is the correct/preferable way:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    myPrivateFunction();
    anotherPrivateFunction();

    ...

    $scope.someScopeMethod = function(){
        ...

        anotherPrivateFunction();

        ...
    };

    $scope.anotherScopeMethod = function(){
        ...

        myPrivateFunction();

        ...
    };

    ...

    function myPrivateFunction(){
        //
    }

    function anotherPrivateFunction(){
        //
    }

});
```

Comment: So, you meant AngularJS controllers? You said AngularJS factory... yes, that is how you should do this.

Comment: @NewDev: Oops, I meant to ask about both of them -- question is updated now.

Anyway, should it be different for factories?

Comment: It's a similar idea. At the end of the day, it's just a JavaScript object / function.

Comment: @NewDev: Your comment really helped to clear some misconceptions. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct. Your functions will only be visible inside the scope of your controller constructor function. This is the same for factories and vanilla js where functions declared in functions will only be visible in their parent function context.

Answer (score 1):

In factories it would looks like as below:

```
.factory('my-factory', function(){

      function privareMethodA() {

      }

      var anotherPrivateMethod = function() {

      }

     return {
       publicMethodA = function() {

       },

       publicMethodB = function() {

       }

   };

});
```

So after you inject your factory into another factory or a controller `publicMethodA()` and `publicMethodB()` will be available, but `privateMethodA()` and `anotherPrivatemethod()` won't be accessible from outside of this factory.
Accessibility of controllers are similar to your snippet.